# How to find the optimal value in a function to get the best result?

Tags: python, optimization, equation-solving

This is an example of a bigger data, but imagine I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.04, 0.08, 0.09, 0.07, 0.07],
                   'y':[0.67, 0.46, 0.41, 0.43, 0.40]})
```

I have a equation to calculate new 'y' values that I will call here as 'y_pred':

```
# y_pred = (1 - x) / (1 + c * x)
```

My goal here is to define the best value of 'c' (as it is a constant), but I can't keep changing 'c' manually every time. For example, here I used 'c' as 10:

```
df['y_pred'] = (1 - df['x']) / (1 + 10 * df['x'])
    
r2 = r2_score(df['y'], df['y_pred'])
```

Is there a method or a function I could use to set the best 'c' for me that I will get the best r2 score for my data?

Comment: Scipy's Optimization module is your best starting point - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is slightly trickier because `minimize` from `scipy.optimize` takes functions with single argument only. And that single argument has to be the initial values.

First lets define your function:

```
def my_func(df, c):
    df['y_pred'] = (1 - df['x']) / (1 + c * df['x'])
    return -r2_score(df['y'], df['y_pred'])
```

Note that negative value is returned because we are gonna use a minimization routine. Thus the overall effect is that we are maximizing the function.

Now to get around with single argument thing, we can use `partial` from `functools`.

```
from functools import partial
cost_function = partial(my_func, df)
```

Now the `cost_function` can take one argument only because  `df` is already absorbed. You can test that by using `cost_function(c=10)`, which gives `-0.14321448901325817`.

Rest is the standard minimization code. I used Nelder-Mead but you can try with many other routines from `scipy`.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
x0 = 10 #initial guess
res = minimize(cost_function, x0, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```

That gives:

```
 final_simplex: (array([[14.30974102],
       [14.30974197]]), array([-0.80003086, -0.80003086]))
           fun: -0.8000308591966453
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 48
           nit: 24
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([14.30974102])
```

The function is maximised for `c = res[x] = array([14.30974102])`, where the value is `res[fun] = -0.8000308591966453`. Again note that negative is because we returned negative from the function.